# I would like to leave my math masters program for a PhD program. Will this reflect poorly on my PhD applications and if so how can this be mitigated?

Tags: phd, mathematics, masters, united-states, career-path

I graduated with a bachelors gpa of 3.8+ and unfortunately got rejected from all PhD programs last cycle. I completed my entire undergraduate education in two year because some personal circumstances forced me to rush the degree.

I started a funded masters at a very poorly ranked institution thinking it could improve my PhD application and because I needed to leave home but they only have one faculty member remotely in my area of interest and do not offer the courseload I need.

I earned a 4.0 my first term at this masters but I do not feel I would benefit from continuing. On my PhD applications it is clear I did not fail out of this masters, and my statement of purpose explains that even faculty members at my school gave me PhD application advice for this cycle.

Is there anything else I can do to salvage the situation?

Comment: What country are you applying in? Some of it sounds like US and others not.

Comment: Apologies, I have only ever resided in the US and am applying to US schools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with applying to Ph.D. programs, especially if your current faculty are encouraging you.

That said, barring very unusual circumstances -- if your current program is fully funded and the professors are doing their best to help you, then I'd recommend you remain until you have lined up something better. Opportunities can be found at all schools, including poorly ranked ones. If you are unable to find courses or research opportunities in your favorite subject, why not branch out and try something different for the time being?

If your applications are unsuccessful this cycle, then accomplishing something impressive over the next year might help you next cycle. Good luck.